# Using its been a slice idiom

Tags: idioms, expressions

**It's been a slice**. I don't see this idiom in any of the dictionaries online. Why could be that?
Separately, suppose I had an enjoyable time with my friends and then later that day somebody asks me how was it. Which of these is correct:

- It's been a slice.
- It was a slice.
  Not sure if one could use this modified. It was a slice thingy

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119728/origin-of-its-been-a-slice

Comment: I have heard or read "It's been a slice of heaven." I guess this phrase may be an abbreviation of that. It's saying (with exaggeration) "I've had a good time."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't see this idiom in any of the dictionaries online. Why could that be?

Perhaps because it **isn't** an idiom - at least not yet. For a phrase to be an idiom - defined as *a group of words whose meaning considered as a unit is different from the meanings of each word considered separately* - it has to be *recognisable* by most English speakers and have taken on a unique meaning of its own through wide use. I have certainly never heard this before, and if most native English speakers have to Google it to understand its meaning, it isn't really an idiom.

I note that it has appeared in a couple of recent books and that it was added to a 'wiki' dictionary in June 2022. Perhaps it will catch on, or perhaps you'll forever be explaining it to people. Time will tell.

Comment: I've been familiar with it since at least the 90s. See my answer for more details

Comment: @gotube I used to know a guy who would say 'cool onions' instead of 'cool beans'. Everyone thought he was an idiot.

Comment: I do find this on `wiktionary` and `idioms.thefreedictionary.com` but not on any of the standard dictionaries like oxford, Cambridge, etc. Searching on `google books` it does show some results `https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it%27s+been+a+slice%22`   This is somewhat surprising to me. How come the author's been using this without any standard dictionary having a reference to it?

Comment: @Astralbee The first person I heard use "cool beans" said "cool bananas" instead. I thought people who said "cool beans" were weird until I realized there was only one person who said "cool bananas".

Answer (score -1):

I had never heard this phrase before, but I looked at [Google Ngram  Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%27s%20been%20a%20slice&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) and, while it is very rare, it does occur.

Then I Googled and found the phrase in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/it%27s_been_a_slice).

Given this, your  first choice is correct, and it would probably be understood in context, but it's quite an unusual usage.

Comment: Wikitionary says it's used "when departing" so you wouldn't use it in the context the OP suggests.

Comment: [McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Idioms](https://www.sausd.us/cms/lib/CA01000471/Centricity/domain/1835/dictionaries/Dictionary_of_American_Idioms_.pdf) (2005): ***It ’s been a slice!** Slang. It’s been good. Example usages: **Good-bye and thank you. It’s been a slice!** ... **It’s been a slice. I hope to see you again some day.*** But I seriously doubt it'll ever become "mainstream", since any metaphorical allusion is somewhat lost on me (A slice of *what?* A slice of ***life**?* ***pizza**?*).

Comment: Downvoters: care to comment? Do you not recognize the expression yourself, or is this answer incorrect?

Answer (score -1):

This expression is only used with the present perfect as a shared experience is ending, or as you're leaving an event. It cannot be used in the simple past to describe a past event.

---

Since few seem to know the expression and I've been familiar with it since at least the 90s, I'll add some more info about it.

The shared experience can be a relationship, living situation, shared workplace, vacation, social event, etc.

I've understood it comes from "It's been a slice of life", but it has a more positive feeling than that, so it's not the same thing.

It's commonly used sarcastically, perhaps more often than sincerely.

I'm Canadian, so it might be a Canadianism.

Comment: Downvoters: care to comment? Do you not recognize the expression yourself, or is this answer incorrect?